# What is happening in the following snippet?

Tags: java

I am not able to understand the following snipet. I mean what is happening exactly. Can any one explain me what is happening?

This is the snippet:

```
protected NodeService getUnprotectedNodeService()

   { 

      if (this.unprotectedNodeService == null)
          {
         this.unprotectedNodeService = (NodeService) FacesHelper.getManagedBean(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "nodeService");
      }
      return this.unprotectedNodeService;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sets `this.unprotectedNodeService` if it not set yet(and also returns it..), and if it is already set, it just returns it. 

seems like a caching mechanism to prevent calling heavy methods more then once

Comment: actually it returns `this.unprotectedNodeService` in any case

Comment: @MarcoS: I forgot to write it at the first 'version' of the answer, but I immediately editted it...look at the editted answer.

Comment: sorry: I've must have seen the first version of your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

- If `this.unprotectedNodeService` is
  null, a bean is looked up and
  stored in
  `this.unprotectedNodeService`.
- `this.unprotectedNodeService` is returned from the function.

This is an example of [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

If the `unprotectedNodeService` instance variable is not set, it's looking up a `ManagedBean` stored in scope under the "`nodeService`" key.  If it doesn't exist it will get created.  It's being casted to a `NodeService` Object and returned, as well as being set as the instance variable.  This must be from a JSF application.  Look in `faces-config.xml` or relevant `@ManagedBean` annotations to find more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is the *lazy initializion* pattern.

The field `unprotectedNodeService` is initialized when it's first used (and not before).

Note that this code is not thread safe.